# If value occurs at least once in column B, fill for each sample with a given value in column A

Tags: r

I am attempting to  create a new column (C) that has TRUE/FALSE value.

There are a number of possible values for Column A, and each also has a TRUE/FALSE value shown in Column B.

For each value of column A, if at least one row is "TRUE" in column B, I want all of column C to be TRUE for that value. For example...

```
A   B
1   TRUE
1   FALSE
1   FALSE
1   FALSE
2   TRUE
2   FALSE
2   FALSE
3   FALSE
3   FALSE
4   TRUE
4   FALSE
4   FALSE
```

The return that I want looks like:

```
A   B      C
1   TRUE   TRUE
1   FALSE   TRUE
1   FALSE   TRUE
1   FALSE   TRUE
2   TRUE   TRUE
2   FALSE   TRUE
2   FALSE   TRUE
3   FALSE   FALSE
3   FALSE   FALSE
4   TRUE   TRUE
4   FALSE   TRUE
4   FALSE   TRUE
```

The issue is that, while I could enter an ifelse statement to define TRUE/FALSE for each value in column A manually, I have upward of 100 different values in column A.

So, as stated: if at least one row is TRUE per value in column A, all rows for that value need to be defined as TRUE in column C.

I do not know how to get R to perform such an operation, and any advice would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R method with `any` and grouping with `ave`

```
df$c <- ave(df$B, df$A, FUN=any)
df
   A     B     c
1  1  TRUE  TRUE
2  1 FALSE  TRUE
3  1 FALSE  TRUE
4  1 FALSE  TRUE
5  2  TRUE  TRUE
6  2 FALSE  TRUE
7  2 FALSE  TRUE
8  3 FALSE FALSE
9  3 FALSE FALSE
10 4  TRUE  TRUE
11 4 FALSE  TRUE
12 4 FALSE  TRUE
```

`any` returns TRUE if any values in the vector are TRUE. This is performed by group with `ave`.

**data**

```
df <- 
structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), B = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("A", "B"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the speedy reply.

Unfortunately while the code runs without errors, it populates column C with NA.

Hang on, just noticed you've edited the code -- trying again.

Comment: It works for the example that you provided. If you have NAs either one of your vectors, then the function might return NAs for that group. Also, I named the data.frame df, and if you gave it an alternative name, you should replace df with that name.

Comment: The `any` function has a `na.rm` argument

Comment: This is true. However, if any value in the vector is TRUE, then `any` will return TRUE. Using na.rm =TRUE is only important in turning an NA value into a FALSE value (conditional on having at least one FALSE and no TRUEs).

Comment: Or other option is `data.table` `setDT(df)[, c := any(B), A]`

Comment: @lmo Ran `df$B[is.na(df.final$B)] <- 'FALSE'` to remove _NA_s from the column, and when I run `df$c <- ave(df$B, df$A, FUN=any)` it still populates the column with _NA_s, in spite of column B having no _NA_ values. About to give your suggestion a shot, @akrun

Comment: @JackReid  It is the similar suggestion as lmo.  Please check if you have only  TRUE/FALSE (logical column)

Comment: BTW, the quote i.e. 'FALSE' would create a problem as it converts to character vector.  It should be `FALSE`

Comment: If you copy the data frame in my post (which replicates the one in your example) and then run my code, do you get any NAs? If no, then there is something in your data that is different than in your example. Perhaps your column is character rather than logical? you can use `str(df)` to check and use `as.logical` to convert it.

Comment: @lmo the reasoning, it turns out, is even more embarrassing -- I'd switched df$A and df$B around in my code. It now works perfectly, and I apologise profusely for the confusion. Thank you!